# React: how to edit DOM of HTML fragment

Tags: reactjs, dom, gatsby

I have a text string that is an HTML fragment. When wrapped by `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` it gets rendered just fine. Now, I need to manipulate the fragment slightly, for example I need to add/edit attributes to one or more of the tags, perhaps add or delete an element, etc.

I have tried using:

- native `DOMParser` - worked great in-browser, but webpack doesn't have access
- `jsdom` - not compatible with webpack
- `xmldom` - out of date, buggy, threw errors on serialization
- `domino` - worked great in the browser, builds worked, but rendered pages were blank, throwing `TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object`

How can I manipulate the DOM of an HTML fragment in React prior to sending it to `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? I am using Gatsby.js on top of React if that makes a difference.

Comment: Are you pulling your content from `MarkdownRemark` nodes?

Comment: @Z.Zlatev No, not markdown. they come from an external source, they are valid HTML, they process fine in `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`. But I would like to do some extra processing first.

Comment: try https://github.com/rehypejs/rehype